# First RoR app. Relational databasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Doing my first project with Ruby on Rails. I have done the basic railsforzombies.org and tryruby.org but looking for a bit of help.

App I am building is around project management.
I am using Devise for authentication.

Multiple users, can have multiple projects. (and projects can have many users)

In each project, will be multiple tasks, that have only one user assigned to each task.

In my project model I have

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

In my task model I have

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :poject
    belongs_to :user
end
```

db.schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140502052149) do

create_table "projects", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "tasks", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "status"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Where I am confused, is how do I automatically link a project to the current user, or link a task to the project that is currently selected (assuming I have a link to create a task from the project view page)..

Very new to this, so open to all suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: `belongs_to` associates a project to only 1 user. You probably want `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Comment: I very much recommend more reading on the subject: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: note typo on your model at line: `belongs_to :poject`